# How to get number, names, and values of components of derived type in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am new to Fortran. I would like to develop a subroutine which prints assigned variable information to a large derived type in Fortran 95. To simplify, lets say we have a derived type declaration and assigmnent as follows:

```
type SubjectType
    character(20) :: genre
    character(20) :: maindude
end type SubjectType

type BookType
    character(20) :: title
    character(20) :: author
    type(SubjectType) :: subject 

end type Booktype

type(Booktype) :: Book

Book%title = "Harry Potter"
Book%author = "JK Rowling"
Book%subject%genre = "Fantasy"
Book%subject%maindude = "Ron Weasley"
```

I would like the output of my program to be a text file as follows:

> Book%title, Harry Potter
>
> Book%author, JK Rowling
>
> Book%subject%genre, Fantasy
>
> Book%subject%maindude, Ron Weasley

In order to achieve this I believe this is what I need to do:

- Determine Number of fields in the derived type at each level. For instance number of fields in the `Booktype` would be 3. Number of fields in `Booktype%SubjectType` would be 2.
- Find a way to relate the field 'number' to the name of the field (perhaps using pointers?)
- loop over all the field numbers and get their names and values.

My question here is twofold. First is my approach correct/will it lead to the intended result? Second How do I accomplish step 1 of this procedure. Namely, how do I get the number of fields in the derived type at each level?

Comment: Use Derived Type Input/Output (DTIO) -Fortran 2003-.

Comment: Don't go this way, don't treat a derived type as an array, this is a road to hell.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than identifying data types/fields by an index number as proposed in the question, I adapted a very basic "key/value container" class<sup>1</sup> to accomplish the task. The idea is to use a couple of derived types that are generic enough to be reused to create an arbitrary number of data fields to represent a variety of book info, and that you can easily access (and/or print).

```
! Start off with a generic DT to represent character string data fields.
type :: Field
    character(len=:), allocatable :: type  !<- A category such as 'book'
    character(len=:), allocatable :: key   !<- Such as 'title' or 'author'
    character(len=:), allocatable :: val   !<- Such as 'Harry Potter' or 'JK Rowling'
end type

! It is simplest to create/use multiple Fields directly in the BookType.
type :: BookType
    character(len=8) :: type = 'BookType'
    type(Field), dimension(:), allocatable :: fields
    integer :: size = 0
    contains
        procedure, pass :: valueFromKey
end type

! Create a container to hold each BookType created.
type :: BookCollection
    type(BookType), dimension(:), allocatable :: book
end type
```

I'll provide the function `valueFromKey` as an example for how to return the value corresponding to a given key.

```
function valueFromKey(self, key) 
    implicit none
    class(BookType) :: self
    character(*), intent(in) :: key
    character(len=:), allocatable :: valueFromKey
    integer :: i
    logical :: val_is_found

    val_is_found = .False.
    do i = 1,self%size 
        if (trim(key) == self%fields(i)%key) then
            valueFromKey = self%fields(i)%val
            val_is_found = .True.
            exit
        endif
    enddo

    if (.not. val_is_found) then
        valueFromKey = "None"
    endif
end function valueFromKey
```

Put all of the above code in a module. I've left out a few helper functions since they aren't necessary to answer the question and provide a working solution. You will see one of them (`newBook`) used in the example program below, though. Note that the loop over fields prints all of the existing data, which may vary from book to book. OTH, requesting `valueFromKey` for any key not in the book data will return the string 'None'.

```
! Example usage:
program main
    use BookModule
    implicit none
    integer :: i, j
    character(len=6) :: num
    type(BookCollection) :: MyBooks

    allocate(MyBooks%book(2))
    MyBooks%book(1) = newBook(keys=['title', 'author', 'date', 'genre', 'lead'], values=["Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", "1997", "Fantasy", "Ron Weasley"])
    MyBooks%book(2) = newBook(keys=['title', 'author', 'lead'], values=["1984", "George Orwell", "Winston Smith"])

    print *, "LOOP OVER BOOK COLLECTION"
    do i = 1, size(MyBooks%book)
        write(num, '(i6)') i
        print *, "Item ", adjustl(num)
        do j = 1, MyBooks%book(i)%size 
            print *, MyBooks%book(i)%type, ", ", MyBooks%book(i)%fields(j)%type, ", ", MyBooks%book(i)%fields(j)%key, ", ", MyBooks%book(i)%fields(j)%val
        enddo
        print *
    enddo

    print *, "GET FIELD VALUE FROM KEY"
    print *, " Title:  ", MyBooks%book(1)%valueFromKey('title')
    print *, " Author: ", MyBooks%book(1)%valueFromKey('author')
    print *, " Date:   ", MyBooks%book(1)%valueFromKey('date')
    print *
    print *, " Title:  ", MyBooks%book(2)%valueFromKey('title')
    print *, " Author: ", MyBooks%book(2)%valueFromKey('author')
    print *, " Date:   ", MyBooks%book(2)%valueFromKey('date')
end program main
```

Example output:

```
 LOOP OVER BOOK COLLECTION
 Item 1
 BookType, book, title, Harry Potter
 BookType, book, author, JK Rowling
 BookType, book, date, 1997
 BookType, subject, genre, Fantasy
 BookType, subject, lead, Ron Weasley

 Item 2
 BookType, book, title, 1984
 BookType, book, author, George Orwell
 BookType, subject, lead, Winston Smith

 GET FIELD VALUE FROM KEY
  Title:  Harry Potter
  Author: JK Rowling
  Date:   1997

  Title:  1984
  Author: George Orwell
  Date:   None
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> The basic 'key/value container' class mentioned here lacks any hash/mapping/dictionary-like functionality; lookups work only by looping over data members until the key is found, and then grabbing the corresponding value. It is really only suitable for small to medium size datasets.</sub>